# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery'

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.5

I receive this error when I put the following code:

```
var rec = (bNoTracking ? tblOrders.AsNoTracking() : tblOrders);
...
...
...
//error on next line: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<LocalDB.tblOrder>' to 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<LocalDB.tblOrder>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
rec = rec.Where(x => (x.WarehouseId == iWarehouseId) && (x.OrderId == iOrderId));
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks :)

Comment: If you know the result of `rec.Where` is of type `IQueryable<T>`, use an explicit cast. Otherwise, don't reuse `rec`, use a new `var` and work with that instead.

Comment: @Orphid, using a new var works as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rec` variable is typed implicitly as a `DbQuery<tblOrder>` object (because `tblOrders` is a `DbQuery<tblOrder>` object, and [`DbQuery<T>.AsNoTracking`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt155064.aspx) returns an object of the same type).

So, your `var` declaration looks like that to the compiler:

```
DbQuery<tblOrder> rec = (bNoTracking ? tblOrders.AsNoTracking() : tblOrders);
```

However, [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx) is only defined to return an `IQueryable<T>` object, which does not necessarily fit as a `DbQuery<tblOrder>` object.

It should be possible to avoid these issues with an explicit typing of the `rec` variable:

```
IQueryable<tblOrder> rec = (bNoTracking ? tblOrders.AsNoTracking() : tblOrders);
```

Comment: Thanks. I was going to create a new var! This is better!